# How to import Pandas into Jupyter notebook on iPad through Juno?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter

I am using an iPad running Juno from Jupyter notebook and it is giving a traceback when I try and import pandas. It’s saying module doesn’t exist. It will import numpy just fine

Comment: Isn't Juno made to connect to pre-existing servers? In that case the server client is missing pandas.

Comment: I’m running in the server Jupyter sets up for iPads and iPhone and I’m assuming now that they do not have pandas. I emailed them to see what they have to say but may take a while

Comment: Oh, ok. Well you can post your answer here later.

Answer (score 0):

You can import Pandas if you connect to the Azure Notebooks Server. For this, however, you need to upgrade to the paid version of the app and have a [Microsoft Azure Notebooks](https://notebooks.azure.com/) account.